# Python dictionary append

Tags: python, dictionary

I have trouble making my code work. I  post only relevant part of the code.
File im using is in this page https://programmeerimine.cs.ut.ee/_downloads/lapsed.txt
First number is parent and 2nd his child. I also had different filed which translated numbers into name. (I made list ID_name it works fine i checked)
This other part of the code works fine except when I'm trying to add value to existing key.I get error `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'`

```
for line in f:
    part=line.split(" ")
    parent=part[0]
    kid=part[1].strip()
    for el in ID_name:
        if parent == el[0]:
            parent=el[1]

        if kid == el[0]:
            kid=el[1]
    if parent not in parents.keys():
        parents[parent]=kid
    else:
        parents[parent].append(kid)
```

Comment: You can't use append in dictionaries...append is used with list...To add new data in a dictionary, you need to do this my_dict['itemkey'] = itemvalue

Comment: try `parents[parent]+kid` in the else part

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The append function you're referencing only works for lists: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html

If you want to add a new key/value pair to a dictionary, use: dictionary['key'] = value .

You can also opt for: dictionary.update({'key': value}), which works well for adding multiple key/value pairs at once.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize a `list` rather than just adding the object. Change this:

```
parents[parent]=kid
```

to this:

```
parents[parent] = [kid]
```

This will give you a `list` to which you can `append()` new objects, rather than just a string.

Comment: `parent` must be set as a list at the very beginning, instead of `parent=part[0]`, it should be `parent=[part[0]]` and then you can use appropriate list methods such as `.append`.

Comment: The error comes at the `append()`, because `kid` is a string and `append()` doesn't work on strings. `parent` is just the key. In fact, if you try to set `parent` to a `list`, you won't be able to use it as a key at all. `parents` is the dictionary, `parent` is the key, and the values are intended to be a list of `kid`.